# I have a question about Bubble Process in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When using event of function in `addEventlistener()`, does the bubble process run when using `event.target`?

Comment: Almost all the events "bubble" , If that's what you wanted to know

Comment: Can you stop bubbleing while using event.target?

Comment: Yes, you can check my answer

Comment: The answer to the actual question is no, the bubble process starts when the event fires.

Comment: For example,Does that mean you can't stop the bubble process while using " let something = event.target.parentNode"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all the events "Bubble"

But, if you want to stop an event from "bubbling" then you can use:

`event.stopPropagation()`

If you want to stop the event flow from event target to top element in DOM, `event.stopPropagation()` method stops the event to travel to the bottom to top.